# Android 4.0 apps crash on keyboard show

Tags: crashes

I have Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 with Android 4.0.3. Since few hours ago, applications started to crash when they try to show keyboard... I don't know what can be the reason of these crashed, I was just typing in GTalk when it first appeared. And it doesn't matter what keyboard to use (Samsung or custom keyboard). Also I can not even send report, because report tool crashes too.

I have no idea where to write, what to google and what to do. Can you help me?

Comment: Install [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) from your PC (you have to login with your Google account to see your tab) and search your device 's log for pointers. You can also try to clear application data in the app settings for your keyboard, but first see what your logs say.

Comment: aLogCat says that the problem is in the clipboard... I am novice to android and still don't know what to do :)  
http://imageshack.us/f/16/screenshot2012110401022.png/

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue for a proprietary Samsung TouchWiz addon (see [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1655619) and a recent user review for [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper). You might also circumvent the built-in clipboard manager by installing a 3rd party [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper). If that also doesn't work: Try to clear the app data for an app called 'android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExmanager' or 'android.sec.clipboard'. BTW: Is your tab rooted (XDA has a solution then)

Comment: PS: I found this by googling for the first error output from your logs (*failed to obtaining clipboardEx service*) to find all those hints.